# Dual of Lagrange Dual

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

For linear programming, it's well known that the dual of the dual is the primal. I'm wondering if it is the case for Lagrange duality, and I'm having a hard time showing this.

Notationally, let the primal problem be:

$$\text{minimize } \quad f_0(x)$$
$$\text{subject to } \quad f_i(x) \leq 0, \quad i = 1, \dots, m$$

And the dual be:

$$\text{minimize } \quad -g(\lambda) = - \inf_x L(x, \lambda)$$
$$\text{subject to } \quad -\lambda \leq 0$$

Where $L(x,\lambda) = f_0(x) + \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i f_i(x)$ is the Lagrangian.

I suspect it isn't true in general that the dual of dual is the primal. However, intuitively when I hear the term dual I assume that the dual of the dual should be the primal, so this got me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lagrange dual is always a convex optimization problem even for non convex problems. So the dual of the dual is convex. Thus you are correct that the dual of the dual is not always the primal. There is another answered question related to yours here : [the dual of the dual is the primal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329501/the-dual-of-the-dual-is-the-primal)