# How to form a dual problem in convex optimization (in a broad view)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

After reading some papers, this problem confuses me.

There are different forms of dual problem to the primal problem: 
$$\underset{x}\min \ \ f(x)$$
where $f(x)$ is a convex function.

1. By forming the Lagrangian and doing:(S. Boyd convex optimization ch. 6)
   $$\underset{\lambda\geq 0}\sup \underset{x}\inf \ \ L(x,\lambda)$$
2. Form the lower linear model: (Y. Nesterov `Primal-dual subgradient methods for convex optimization`)

   [image]
   The minimization of the right hand side is the lower bound of the primal problem.

And the paper says

> dual problem can be posed in different forms depending on the structure of the problem.

My questions is:

> How to get intuition or an efficient observation to form a dual problem based on the structure of the primal problem? (In a broad view and sense)

Comment: This thread might be relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223235/please-explain-the-intuition-behind-the-dual-problem-in-optimization

Comment: @dohmatob You are correct.

Comment: N.B.: That Nesterov paper is quite dated. What kind of problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to come up with new idea from these old papers; and one approach is try to adapt the algorithm existing; therefore, I want to build a big picture in this direction. However, I am too junior, so I just ask a suggestion or a possible cut-in point.

Comment: The rule should be: if you can algorithmically solve the primal problem directly, do not resort to the dual. If you do, dualise only those constraints which will allow you to solve the dual problem - don't overdualise - unless you gain something, e.g., the dual problem you come up with has a better structure and/or can be solved in a distributed manner. More often than not, there are more than one efficient ways to form a dual problem.

Additionally, there are more parts of the primal problem than constraints one may dualise and these become more evident in the framework of Fenchel duality.