# How to define duality in optimization

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Whenever I see articles or books about a $(P)$ optimization problem, they find the dual using the Lagrangian and then call it $$(D)=``\text{Lagrangian dual problem of }(P)"$$ I understand that the purpose of this is to get lower bounds if $(P)$ is maximization problem, so my questions are the following

1. Are there other ways to get to the same problem $(D)$ without using the Lagrangian?
2. How else can I construct lower bounds for the optimal value of my problem $(P)$? That is, is there a method that finds a problem $ (D ') $ that gives me better lower limits than $ (D) $?

Comment: You might be interested in the perturbation viewpoint on the dual problem, which I wrote about here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/624633/40119

Comment: thank you very much littleO.

Comment: One good thing to be aware of is the Fenchel-Rockafellar approach to duality, where the primal problem is to minimize $f(x) + g(Ax)$ and the dual problem is to minimize $f^*(-A^T z) + g^*(z)$. Here $f^*$ and $g^*$ are the convex conjugates of $f$ and $g$, respectively. The Fenchel-Rockafellar dual problem is the same as the Lagrange dual problem you'd obtain by reformulating the primal problem as minimizing $f(x) + g(y)$ subject to $y = Ax$.