# 'Meaning' and interpretation of convex conjugate

Tags: convex-optimization

In the field of *convex optimization*, and in particular on prof. *Stephen Boyd*'s lecture slides, the **conjugate** $f^*$ of a function $f$ is defined to be

$$ f^*(y) = \sup_{x \in domf} (y^Tx - f(x))$$

I'm just trying to better understand this definition (what does it mean exactly? What is the geometrical interpretation?) and figure out how this is actually used in concrete. For sure, an interesting point is that $f^*$ is convex even if $f$ is not.

Many thanks,

James

Comment: This is the Legendre transformation. The Wikipedia article probably has good information on it: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation

Comment: See maybe [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/639945) to a similar question.

Comment: I strongly recommend [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1147).