# Is duality in optimization essentially a Legendre transform?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, legendre-transformation

I have seen places where duality in optimization, such as in Linear Programming (Primal LP vs dual LP), is not really explained, but some "recipes" are given to write down a dual LP program, if given a primal LP program. But then somewhere else (both are wikipedia articles actually), a link with Lagrange multipliers is made. And now things are starting to make more sense in my brain. The dual variables are nothing but Lagrange multipliers!

But still, I would like to find a reference, preferably that I could find online for free, which is a concise explanation of duality from that Lagrange multipliers point of view.

On one hand, it seems like a not very deep fact, such a duality, yet, I am having issues understanding really how it works. Are primal LP programs and their dual LP  programs nothing but analogues of Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formulations, and is duality essentially nothing but a Legendre transform? If true, then I would like to see it explained this way, if possible.

Edit: according to the article [The concept of duality in convex analysis, and the characterization of
the Legendre transform](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v169-n2-p08.pdf), by Shiri Artstein-Avidan and Vitali Milman, it does look like my intuition is basically correct.

Edit 2: I found the following helpful: some notes by David Knowles at Stanford on [Lagrangian Duality](https://www-cs.stanford.edu/people/davidknowles/lagrangian_duality.pdf).

Comment: Relevant thread: [Please explain the intuition behind the dual problem in optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/223235/40119). The answer I posted explains the connection between the dual problem and the Legendre transform.

Comment: Thank you, I happened to have found it right when you posted that comment!